# How to generate a unique hash value based on current timestamp?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

I want to generate a unique hash value based on the current timestamp. I tried to get the current timestamp by `block.timestamp` but it gives me the same number every time so my generated hash value is not unique. How do I deal with this?

```
    function generateUniqueHash() public onlyOwner returns (bytes32) {
        return keccak256(abi.encodePacked("secret", block.timestamp));
    }
```

Comment: Where are you testing this? Remix?

Comment: @pbsh Yes I tested in both remix and node solc

Comment: why the function is not "public view"? and why are you using "onlyOwner" , it does not change the state of the contract?

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine on my end:

first try:

```
{
    "0": "bytes32: 0x4fa4ee671213fd09d919f9e20942fca229302f8636cc722667a844518fdafe1d"
}
```

second try:

```
{
    "0": "bytes32: 0x1be2ff47184adae85d9ed4e084d5cab1be81a64dee3601dacafe7ae7b90b6d07"
}
```

and the third one:

```
{
    "0": "bytes32: 0xc9fe1eefcfec97a5981d0535e1d594957337ce7086a8431d14ed50942ec9437d"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is for a commercial project, please note that block.timestamp is not the best source of entropy/randomness as miners can (almost) freely set it: [Block Timestamp Manipulation](https://solidity-by-example.org/hacks/block-timestamp-manipulation/)

Ex: if you are designing a money game where the outcome depends on that data, and if there is BIG money involved, it is always possible for a miner to include a transaction to your contract and predict, based on your formula, which particular value of block.timestamp will give them an advantage.

A good alternative would be to use [Chainlink VRF](https://blog.chain.link/random-number-generation-solidity/)

Otherwise, for prototyping or projects not involving money, it is of course perfectly fine to use block.timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a unique identifier like the transaction hash or the block number to generate a unique hash value.

Here is an example using the transaction hash:

```
function generateUniqueHash() public onlyOwner returns (bytes32) {
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked("secret", tx.hash));
}
```

And here is an example using the block number:

```
function generateUniqueHash() public onlyOwner returns (bytes32) {
    return keccak256(abi.encodePacked("secret", block.number));
}
```

Note that the block number and transaction hash can be easily accessed within a contract, so you should use them with caution as they can potentially be exploited by attackers.